# Cloud Build fails due to Cloud Function container not being ready yet

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

we have a Google cloudbuild pipeline that does the following:

- Create a temp function
- Run some tests
- Deploy the production function

However, the second step often fails due to the first container not being ready yet:

```
Step #3: Unexpected token '<' at 2:1
Step #3: <html><head>
Step #3:  site unreachable
```

looks like it is returning some placeholder html from nginx.

How can we fix that?
Currently, we just put an ugly `sleep` between steps

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look to the Cloud Functions API, there you can find the operations endpoint that will tell you if the operation is finished or not (assuming v1, otherwise look below): https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/get

The operation is the same Id that is returned in the creation operation. Also you can list them with the list endpoint (in the same doc).